# C++ wiringPi Crash

Tags: c++, gpio, pwm, wiringpi

I am trying to create a program that controls a servo motor using wiringPi.
However, as soon as I call

```
wiringPiSetupGPIO();
```

my Pi crashes. Any Idea why this might be happening?

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <wiringPi.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    wiringPiSetupGpio();

    pinMode(18, PWM_OUTPUT);
    pwmSetMode(PWM_MODE_BAL);
    pwmSetClock(192);
    pwmSetRange(2000);
    pwmWrite(18, 200);
}
```

Comment: A 2 second search finds [this](http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/) _should one of the wiringPi setup functions fail, then it would be considered a fatal program fault and the program execution will be terminated at that point with an error message printed on the terminal._ What's the error message?

Comment: What version of WiringPi?

Answer (score 0):

Try using sudo to compile and run it as sudo. It made my code run when I was using ponMode(pin #, PWM_OUTPUT)